# Динамическое программное управление фрагментами в Android

Tags: android, android-fragment

Делаю приложение для Android (на Java) и возник ряд вопросов по фрагментам и в целом.

У меня главная страница приложения представляет собой вертикальный список карточек, каждая из которых содержит одинаковые поля с разной информацией в них. Сам список я сделал из `LinearLayout`, в него динамически добавляются/убираются карточки. Каждая карточка это экземпляр одного фрагмента. Информация в карточках должна синхронно обновляться по таймеру (раз в 30 секунд).

Разметка фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.Fragment1">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/example"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Разметка основной активности:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/card_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Сразу скажу, что мне не нужно, чтобы было просто кликабельное меню, которое открывало отдельно на экран фрагменты по очереди, мне нужно именно чтобы в общем вертикальном списке отображались все карточки и информация на них динамически менялась.

Также нужно динамически добавлять и убирать карточки.

Я идентифицирую фрагменты через TAG, то есть ищу их через `findFragmentByTag` с помощью `getFragmentManager()`, добавляю новые фрагменты этим же менеджером. **Но, это не работает!**

Если я добавляю более 1 экземпляра фрагмента (теги разные), отображается только первый.
Когда я хочу найти фрагмент по тегу, то он не находится (`null`), соответственно, выставить его поля я не могу.

Код активности фрагмента:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    TextView example;

    public Fragment1() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        example = view.findViewById(R.id.example);

        return view;
    }
```

Код основной активности:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        // добавляем фрагменты
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.card_container, new Fragment1(), "card1")
                .add(R.id.card_container, new Fragment1(), "card2")
                .commit();

        fragmentManager
            .executePendingTransactions();

        Fragment1 card1 = (Fragment1) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("card1");
        TextView example = card1.getView().findViewById(R.id.example);
        example.setText("Example");
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать это все, чтобы оно работало? Желательно с простейшими примерами, ибо в андроид-разработке я новичок.

**UDP:** Обновил код, исправил указанную в комментариях ошибку с ID, исправил ошибку с null при поиске фрагмента, но теперь получаю ошибку при поиске полей в фрагменте: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: код нужен, по вашему описанию невозможно понять, что там у вас происходит

Comment: добавил код для примера

Comment: В коде что-то странное. По идее commit запускает асинхронную операцию и сразу после него ни один фрагмент добавленный может не найтись. Попробуйте commitNow. Также сомневаюсь, что простое добавление в LinearLayout выстроит фрагменты по вертикали. Ну и вы явно не тот ID указаваете когда добавляете фрагмент.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание насчет ID, проглядел, теперь хотя бы все экземпляры фрагмента показываются. Проблему насчет null при поиске экземпляра фрагмента решил, добавив после commit() вот это: fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions(); , но осталась проблема с тем, что у меня в этом экземпляре фрагмента не находится текстовое поле, к примеру TextView example = getView().findViewById(R.id.example);

Comment: Текстовое поле, скорее всего, не находится по аналогичной причине - загрузка и отображение разметки происходит не синхронно. Т.о.  getView() будет null возвращать, если сразу после добавления фрагмента это вызывать. Наверное, вам подойдёт вариант с вызовом метода-сеттера на самом фрагменте, с тем, чтобы в onViewCreated оного сетить текст внутри нужного фрагмента из значения переменной, заданной во внешнем фрагменте. Хотя такое, вообще, лучше уж через аргументы фрагмента сделать, но тут может, конечно, зависеть от условий задачи.